# HTML onclick not passing this.name in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, onclick

I'm attempting a hide show toggling script using jquery. The name of the label is passed into the jquery script and the id of the information is used to trigger a hide show. works great in IE but i can't get it in safari. the onclick returns undefined.

```
    <span id="fontlabel" name="fontinfo" style="cursor:pointer; color:#06C;" 
    onclick="showfont(this.name)">Font List for Input</span>
    <span id="stagenamefont" class="fontsettings"> ...stuff...</span>

    function showfont(name)
    {
if($('#'+name).is(':visible')== false)
{
$('#'+name).show();
}else{
$('#'+name).hide();
}
     }
```

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/) — span elements don't have a name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery. Let's do this the right way:

#### HTML

```
<span id="fontlabel" rel="fontinfo">Font List for Input</span>
<span id="stagenamefont" class="fontsettings"> ...stuff...</span>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    function showfont()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#'+id).toggle();
    }

    $('#fontlabel').click(showfont);
});
```

#### Demo http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/dzrJg/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be best to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fontlabel").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#"+name).toggle();
    });
});


<span id="fontlabel" rel="fontinfo" style="cursor:pointer; color:#06C;">Font List for Input</span>
<span id="stagenamefont" class="fontsettings"> ...stuff...</span>
<br />
<span id="fontinfo"> font settings here</span>
```

Try this and see if that works

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/FCTRq/)